# Strip pandas data frame and extract list per exchange of tickers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strip

I am working on a data frame, which consists of the name of company, the ticker id, as well as the ticker exchange id. The code for scraping the data works fine. Below is the output of the data.

```
    Company name          (Company symbol, Company exchange)
0   Abbott Laboratories   (ABT, NYQ)
1   ABBVIE                (ABBV, NYQ)
2   ASML.AS               (ASML.AS, AMS)
3   AD.AS                 (AD.AS, AMS) 

Index(['Company name', ('Company symbol', 'Company exchange')], dtype='object')
type(df_companies)= pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I have tried to strip the redundant symbols (), with codes like:

```
df[df_companies.columns] = df_companies.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df_companies.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

These codes didn't work, they resulted in NaN. I tried to transpose the data frame, but that didn't help as well. The idea is to create the df_companies like this:

```
Company name              Company symbol  Company exchange
0   Abbott Laboratories   ABT             NYQ
1   ABBVIE                ABBV            NYQ
2   ASML.AS               ASML.AS         AMS
3   AD.AS                 AD.AS           AMS
```

The final idea is to create a list per exchange, like this:

```
NYQ=['ABT', 'ABBV']
AMS=['ASMl.AS', 'AD.AS']
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `explode` on the column?  It's hard to tell if that's a string or tuple, but if it's the latter perhaps this would get you closer to what you want.

Comment: I tried this; df_companies.explode(('Company symbol', 'Company exchange')). The code stripped the ticker and exchange, but copies the company name and sets the ticker id and the ticker exchange below each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first remove the `()` brackets from your symbol/exchange column, and then  [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on `,` with `expand=True`:

```
df[['Company Symbol','Company Exchange']] = df['(Company symbol, Company exchange)'].str.strip('()')\
                                        .str.split(',',expand=True)
df.drop('(Company symbol, Company exchange)',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Which gives:

```
          Company name Company Symbol Company Exchange
0  Abbott Laboratories            ABT              NYQ
1               ABBVIE           ABBV              NYQ
2              ASML.AS        ASML.AS              AMS
3                AD.AS          AD.AS              AMS
```

And lastly:

```
>>> df.groupby('Company Exchange')['Company Symbol'].agg(list)

Company Exchange
 AMS    [ASML.AS, AD.AS]
 NYQ         [ABT, ABBV]
```

Sample `df`:

```
>>> df.to_dict()

{'Company name': {0: 'Abbott Laboratories',
  1: 'ABBVIE',
  2: 'ASML.AS',
  3: 'AD.AS'},
 '(Company symbol, Company exchange)': {0: '(ABT, NYQ)',
  1: '(ABBV, NYQ)',
  2: '(ASML.AS, AMS)',
  3: '(AD.AS, AMS)'}}
```

**Please check the last code below:**

```
df.columns = [str(s).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace("'",'') for s in df.columns]
df[['Company Symbol','Company Exchange']] = pd.DataFrame(df["Company symbol, Company exchange"].tolist(), index=df.index)
df.drop("Company symbol, Company exchange",axis=1,inplace=True)
df.groupby('Company Exchange')['Company Symbol'].agg(list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have now to figure out on how to solve the annoying error: KeyError: '(Company symbol, Company exhange)'

Comment: sorry I think I had a typo. I had ```exhange``` and not ```exchange```. I corrected it now.

Comment: please have a look now. I hope that works for you

Answer (score 1):

you can use groupby to aggregate another column to a list

```
data = {
    "Company exchange": ["NYQ", "NYQ", "AMS", "AMS"],
    "Company Symbol" : ["ABT", "ABBV", "ASML.AS", "AD.AS"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output :

[image]

```
df.groupby('Company exchange')['Company Symbol'].apply(list)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> data = {
...    "Company name": ["Abbott Laboratories", "ABBVIE", "ASML.AS", "AD.AS"],
...    "(Company symbol, Company exchange)" : ["(ABT, NYQ)", "(ABBV, NYQ)", "(ASML.AS, AMS)", "(AD.AS, AMS)"]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
    Company name        (Company symbol, Company exchange)
0   Abbott Laboratories (ABT, NYQ)
1   ABBVIE              (ABBV, NYQ)
2   ASML.AS             (ASML.AS, AMS)
3   AD.AS               (AD.AS, AMS)
```

We start to replace the `()` by `[]` to work with lists intead of tuples :

```py
>>> df["(Company symbol, Company exchange)"] = df["(Company symbol, Company exchange)"].replace(to_replace='\(', value="[", regex=True)
>>> df["(Company symbol, Company exchange)"] = df["(Company symbol, Company exchange)"].replace(to_replace='\)', value="]", regex=True)
>>> df
    Company name        (Company symbol, Company exchange)
0   Abbott Laboratories [ABT, NYQ]
1   ABBVIE              [ABBV, NYQ]
2   ASML.AS             [ASML.AS, AMS]
3   AD.AS               [AD.AS, AMS]
```

Now we can "explode" the data inside the brackets in two new columns :

```py
>>> df[['Company symbol','Company exchange']] = pd.DataFrame(df["(Company symbol, Company exchange)"].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(',')).tolist(), index= df.index)
>>> df
    Company name        (Company symbol, Company exchange)  Company symbol  Company exchange
0   Abbott Laboratories [ABT, NYQ]                          ABT             NYQ
1   ABBVIE              [ABBV, NYQ]                         ABBV            NYQ
2   ASML.AS             [ASML.AS, AMS]                      ASML.AS         AMS
3   AD.AS               [AD.AS, AMS]                        AD.AS           AMS
```

To finish and get the expected result, we can use a `groupby` and get the wanted lists :

```py
>>> df.groupby('Company exchange')['Company symbol'].apply(list)
Company exchange
 AMS    [ASML.AS, AD.AS]
 NYQ         [ABT, ABBV]
Name: Company symbol, dtype: object
```